# Creating random Numbers, store them in array and sort them in two listboxes c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am trying to generate random `int` numbers, once I Generate them I want to store them in a `listBox`, after this sort them in second `listBox`. The code that I have:

```
        int Min = 0;
        int Max = 6;

        // this declares an integer array with 5 elements
        // and initializes all of them to their default value
        // which is zero
        int[] test2 = new int[6];

        Random randNum = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i < test2.Length; i++)
        {
            test2[i] = randNum.Next(Min, Max);    
        }
        arrayListbox.ItemsSource = test2;
        Array.Sort(test2);
        foreach (int value in test2)
        {
            arrayListboxOrder.ItemsSource = test2;
        }
```

Comment: OK, so what's wrong, what problem are you having?

Comment: and the prize for the "entirely redundant and unnecessary comment award" goes to: "this declares an integer array with 5 elements and initializes all of them to their default value which is zero". Also, it gets it wrong: it has 6 elements, not 5.

Comment: I notice the comment is also wrong ...

Comment: I have two list with the same content, my purpose is to have two different lists one with the random numbers(not sorted) and one more again the random numbers(sorted)

Comment: Which is a good example as to _why_ you never use comments like this

Comment: Not to mention the for loop starts at 1, where it should be 0 because arrays are zero-based (assuming that's what you want to do).

Comment: Your both listboxes have same source.

Comment: I find it interesting that this is a great example of why you should even future-proof comments lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemsSource` needs to be a different array - otherwise they both fundamentally have the same data. Sort one, sort them "both".

Try:

```
arrayListbox.ItemsSource = test2;
int[] sorted = (int[])test2.Clone();
Array.Sort(sorted);
arrayListboxOrder.ItemsSource = sorted;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int Min = 0;
        int Max = 6;
        // this declares an integer array with 5 elements
        // and initializes all of them to their default value
        // which is zero
        //int[] test2 = new int[6];

        arrayListboxOrder.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(Min, Max).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5).OrderBy(n=>n).ToArray();
```

I saved a snippet here:
http://rextester.com/GBM61947